# Timezone.xml editing

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, timezone

I need to update the Timezone.xml file in my Sharepoint server (2010).
This file hasn't been updated since 2009.

Do I need to add all the "history" tags of all the previous years (there were changes every year)? What's exactly the meaning of this tag?

I've failed so far to find complete info on this.

Also, is there an automatic update instead of editing an xml file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft generally keeps this up to date thru product updates.  Have you reviewed the cumulative update releases to see if this files has been updated?

When you edit the file - you should take the entry you want to change and move it to History node.  This guidance is for 2007 but the file is the same:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/888253

As for the meaning of the tag - it's for dates that may have occurred during that period so your date/time is still correct. I have not played with it - but I imagine if you don't have content with dates from those periods, there is little risk in not having them.